# Workbench end-of-life?

Tags: security, workbench

I have my own instance of Workbench running on Heroku and have recently started receiving the following email after deployment:

> Your recently built app XXXXXX is using the Heroku-16 stack, which is
> deprecated. From May 1st 2021, Heroku-16 will be end-of-life, and apps
> using it will no longer receive security updates, and be run at your
> own risk. From June 1st 2021, builds will no longer be allowed for
> Heroku-16 apps. Please upgrade to a newer stack as soon as possible.
> See the Heroku-16 End-Of-Life FAQ for more details.

A year or so ago I had opened an issue under the project on Github asking if the stack would be updated, and the response indicated that no stack update would be coming and Workbench would eventually be retired completely.

Now that Heroku is announcing the end-of-life for the stack Workbench is built on, is there a similar announcement regarding end-of-life for Workbench itself being made?  I was expecting / hoping to see an announcement on the Workbench login page itself.
Or, has Workbench been completely abandoned at this point so that not even an end-of-life announcement or warning about lack of security updates will be coming?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Heroku, but this [github commit](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/commit/cfd045096ec8207f1d02992e020d3f87f6af05f7) from March 2021 refers to heroku 20, does this keep workbench alive?  (I use the public version)

Answer (score 1):

Today a new version of Workbench was released that included an upgrade of the stack to Heroku-20.  Workbench can live a little while longer!

So I guess I will answer my own question for now -- seems like the answer is "not yet", but would still love to have more definitive communication as to when Workbench will actually be retired so that we can plan accordingly.